# How To: Flask Use Global Logger

Tags: python, logging, flask

How can I tell a Flask application to use a specific instance of a logger that already exists? I have a logger that is already created (and logging) and I'd like to say to my Flask app "hey, use this logger".

All I can see that is possible is to call:

my_flask_app.logger.addHandler(handler)

But I don't want to pass it a handler. Won't that just create a separate logger? I see within the Flask code it call create_logger.

Thoughts? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

In case some else stumbled across this:

```
    app.config["LOGGER_NAME"] = your_logger_name
    app._logger = logger
```

will prevent flask from creating logger, and will use yours instead.

Quite ugly going to `_logger` but didn't find other solution for it.